# Node.js Display data from Mongodb using sockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sockets

I would like to know how you can get data from MongoDB using a specific _id and using sockets. I am using Express, Node.js and MongoDB. This is what I have so far. The id that I use is the one a user gets when he is logged in (passport). Is there some easy and understanding way to fix this? I am quite new at this.

www

```
socket.on('getSlide', function(a) {
  Slides.find({id: a.id}, function(err, slides) {
  if (err) { console.log(err); }
  socket.emit('getSlide', slides);
  });
});
```

Script.js

```
socket.on('getSlide', function(getSlide) {
var id = $(this).val();
socket.emit('getSlide', {id: id});
//append code that follows
});
```

Comment: ... and what is going wrong with the code you've shown here ?

Comment: Well, it does not work. I am not getting an error too, so it is hard for me to find out what's wrong. In my Script.js im just looping through some data that is stored under a same id.

Comment: How are you communicating to MongoDB on the client side (www)? I am guessing you must be using the REST features of mongoose right? Also have you checked your console for errors?